Has MO been reduced to an AI training service, and if so what should we do about it?
I feel like MO is no longer really doing what we intended.
When I look at a new question, rather than trying to help a person, I start thinking: is this a human?  is the question really motivated, or are they just laying down standard sequences of buzzwords and name-drops.   It can be difficult to tell an AI-generated question from ones generated by a grad student "dazzled" by big machines, as they often act quite alike.
Which gets to the point.  Most of my effort is consumed doing exactly what the owner of the AI chatbot wants.  i.e. we are performing a commercial service, and we are not being paid, nor are  we getting any other sort of benefit out of this arrangement.
What options are there other than "raising the gates" and using in-the-flesh authentication, verification that people are human beings?   I suppose a counter-argument is that we could easily verify someone is human and yet all their on-line interactions may still be done by AI chat-bots.  But at least there would be some accountability and there would be a bottleneck on the process.

Just one observation: the vast majority of AI-generated posts appears to be by new unregistered accounts which do not give any clue about the identity of the person behind them.

@StefanKohl correct, but given the nature of the problem if we were to adapt based on that feature, the AI bots would adapt even more quickly.  It seems if we are to adapt to this problem it should be in a direction that AI-bots can not grow towards.

Don't have any real suggestions, just wanted to say: as a regular MO user, I 100% agree with the sentiment that my experience on the site has gotten dramatically worse as a result of the prevelence of AI content.

I haven't noticed significant uptick in such questions, but I've also been rather selective about what posts I've been viewing (or maybe the mods/community have been doing a great job weeding them out before I get to them, or maybe I'm too gullible).  Do we have some statistics on how common such posts are?

@Kimball I created this thread after dealing with a succession of 6 or 8 such chatbot questions/answers that all appeared within a few minutes of each other.     I've certainly noticed an uptick over the past few months.  Currently they appear to come in waves.

@Kimball It could be that a lot of these questions go unnoticed if one does not have sufficiently high reputation to see deleted answers and deleted questions

@Kimball it's definitely trending up.

Perhaps it is more accurate to say some users are interfering with MO being used as intended? That there is plenty of abuse of this forum should, I think, meaningfully be distinguished from the forum not serving its purpose at all, which I think isn't the case. I have both received useful answers to my questions and answered (hopefully) human-generated questions, hopefully usefully, even in the Age of AI.

As a real human who has often found it very hard to ask a question in earnest, given the sometimes quick-to-be-negative-feedback, I think the opposing sentiment is: it's already hard enough to get new(ish) users to ask questions so most suggestions to deter AI/chatbot questions would likely make the site even more insular than it already can feel. (https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/22/the-loop-2-understanding-site-satisfaction-summer-2019/?_ga=2.56061675.112528665.1727457881-10523620.1727457881)

@cheyne: that's a good argument, but of course the counter-argument is nobody will want to participate on a site where they are being abused and lied to. i.e. increasingly users see that even if they want to help people, it's getting increasingly more difficult as real humans are becoming increasingly thin on the ground.

@RyanBudney I completely agree. I don't see a way forward without forcing the company (stack) that owns these sites to pitch in with their resources; at least maybe so that these posts can exist (for those excited to help out the AI tech companies) but they are all flagged? Like... if the community members of mathoverflow solve what is really a problem for the owner of the site, they would have indirectly done free labor regardless. Maybe that's the lesser of evils but still seems they should help.

@cheyne: I think that is beyond their technical capabilities.  Even if they wanted to do something like that, they couldn't.

Just out of curiosity, what use pattern of MO exposes a user to a palpable amount of AI generated posts/answers? I personally mostly browse the front page under the "Active" tab. The AI stuff that I see doesn't feel like a flood, and what I see has usually already been acted on by other users or mods.

@IgorKhavkine My experience isn't too different from that. I have some items suppressed from my display and a few items highlighted.   When I notice a problematic question or answer I often look at other activity by the same user, which leads me to chains of poor questions or answers that I otherwise might have missed.

The problem is just getting worse and worse. I counted like half a dozen new unregistered users asking weird questions, who I highly suspect to be AI, in just the past several hours this evening.

It's become a real nightmare.  I know that you have to register to ask questions on math.se.  Though I would not have supported this in the past, I would support implementing this here as well.  It wouldn't stop the constant flood of bad AI questions altogether, but it might slow it down a little bit.

For the record, here is a post from 2017 about registration for asking on MO: Should MathOverflow require registration to ask a question? (Naturally, the site has changed since then - so the same proposal might be viewed differently now.)

I would support making users register. It's still a step below banning anonymity. And it might help with the AI bot problem. Is there a way we could do a vote on it as a community?

@SamHopkins mods can raise it with the board, for now I suggest making a new meta post specifically about the proposal to require registration, with two CW answers: Yes and No, and let users vote.

@DavidRoberts: done; see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/6042

@Sam thanks for that

I personally think this site would be much better if no postings were anonymous.  I believe MO already asks that answers be reasonably kind.  And if this caused some now anonymous posters to think a bit harder before asking questions, this might serve them well.

I think that MO has a reputation for unkindness, and that this might make contributors who would be welcome here reluctant to participate under their real names.  (I personally do not see it as unkind, except for occasional spats, but, then, I guess a regular participant is unlikely to be someone who sees the site that way, and also unlikely to be familiar with the current new-user experience.)

Previous discussions on this topic: Anonymity Policy and On the role of anonymity in a site dedicated to research-level mathematics.

@LSpice Many people conflate being straightforward and forthright as being rude. I have very rarely encountered people on MO who I would classify as "unfriendly" as in being maliciously nasty for no good reason (though a few users fall under this category, unfortunately). On the other hand, I have seen many users get "offended" that their ego ended up being bruised because they asked a question that either doesn't make sense or is a lot more trivial than thy think.

@Stanley you aren't seeing the people who don't ask their question due to MO's reputation. The slightly difficult culture is well-attested; if you aren't phased by it, you are privileged. It's not about people getting annoyed at being told their low-quality question is off-topic, by the way.

@DavidRoberts I have certainly heard some very negative comments regarding MO from people all over the mathematics community, but I still don't see how to quantify this notion of "unfriendliness". If I can summarize the negative opinions I have heard, it's that MO has rules which are too rigid and "gatekeepers" who think too highly of themselves. I am not sure one can infer that there is a problem with the community at large based on these opinions. If you know something I don't, please share

@StanleyYaoXiao there was a working group a few years back called together by Ravi Vakil, including people whose voices aren't heard here on MO. I don't think I can share anything about it. Feel free to email Ravi about it if this is something you need convincing of.

In the long run, the (ironic) solution may be to implement an AI of our own designed to flag other AI generated posts, and to stay ahead in the whole arms race associated with that approach.
But consider this: AI’s aren’t antithetical to MO’s purpose as I understand it, which is

To explore the bleeding edge of mathematics research.

Certainly bad AI questions/answers like the ones we’ve recieved so far aren’t helpful, and I suspect that this is all AI companies will be able to produce for some years to come (unless some of us personally try to speed the process up).
I would say we keep doing what we’ve been doing; having a fascinating conversation about mathematics. If AI reaches a point where it can participate meaningfully cool, but until
then I don’t mind if some other humans trying to make a thing (remember: this is all AI is) use my input here to try and improve their thing. That’s kind of how I use the site (but for a different thing), so who am I to judge?

I feel like this answer misses Ryan Budney's point that now instead of helping a person learn math, us "real" MO users are helping some company write software.

You are helping a person learn math when you help some company write software (actually you’re helping a group of people, the people at that company). It just isn’t necessarily the math you think you’re teaching them, and if people want to get upset about that it’s their right I suppose. It all seems unnecessarily fussy to me and I can’t see the benefit of stressing over it, but maybe I’m just missing the picture.

@AlecRhea: Math is my job.  While out of a sense of civic mindedness I’m happy to help actual people if they have problems I find interesting, I am not willing to work for free for a for-profit company.  And I resent them lying to try to trick me into working for free.

I don't really see modern AI as having anything to do with mathematics.  These are basically fraud machines, not thinking machines.   So if we got to the point where AI's could really think about mathematics without having mathematicians do all the hard work for them, that would be great.  We're just not there, yet.

@RyanBudney Have you ever made an AI? I’ve made several for various things, and (at least the way i do it) it’s basically glorified matrix algebra combined with error correction, definitely mathematical in nature. Perhaps the resulting AI isn’t able to ‘do math’ yet, but the humans programming them are definitely doing math.

Not sure how this is relevant to the discussion. The nature of AI will change drastically as we go into the future.  Current implementations likely aren't all that relevant to future implementations.

@AndyPutman That’s fair, and perhaps people who view mathematics as a money making endeavor will be turned off by this phenomenon. I do it for the heck of it, so this stuff doesn’t really bother me (even if someone else ultimately profits off my work, eh, whatever — they’re missing the real treasures in life).

@RyanBudney You seem emotionally charged about this whole thing; you claimed there was no math involved, I pointed out how there is, now you’re saying my response to you isn’t relevant to the discussion we’re having lol. I’m gonna sign off for the night, I hope you have a good evening Ryan.

I just wanted to chime in that I disagree fundamentally with your contention that by responding to people spamming this site with LLM content we are somehow advancing mathematics. If the people feeding content into LLMs do not understand what they are posting here, and do not understand the responses given by people here, then how is this advancing anything rather than generating more bullshit?

"You are helping a person learn math when you help some company write software" - I can't express strongly enough how much I disagree with this.

You are being kind of silly, Alec.  You can conflate bland linear algebra with talking about research in mathematics, but this isn't the nature of our discussion here.  You've lost the plot entirely.

I lied, here’s my final input for the night: an AI generated philosophical talk that has helped me greatly in times of strife. Progress and change are inevitable, and it pains me to see you all suffering as a result of inevitable change. I love you guys, and hope you’re all doing well.

@AlecRhea: I don't view mathematics as a "money making endeavor".  That's a total mischaracterization of what I said.  If that was my view, I would be working at a hedge fund or something.  I reiterate: I'm happy to contribute to the general public (and the university I work at even views that as part of my job -- I list things like MO on my annual report each year).  What I'm not willing to do is be tricked/manipulated by a for-profit company.  If a company is making money off my labor, I should be compensated for it (and so should you, and everyone else).

@Alec there are great turmoils in the internal workings of the Stack Exchange system, one visible sign of which was the big moderator strike over the company outlawing actions over AI spam answers (among other things). The company is really really keen to get into the AI space, and there are lots of behind the scenes discussions. Making keen suggestions like this is, while I assume in good faith, blind to what may be happening to the system in the near-to-medium term.

@Alec, you appear to be confused about the nature of the conversation here.

I am quite puzzled by the votes to delete this post. This is supposed to be a discussion, and this answer presents an opinion that is on topic, expressed in a polite way, and does not include offensive or discriminatory language or any such things. Sure, it is an unpopular opinion, but that is not a valid reason to censor it. Vote it down to oblivion, if you will (I did), but why delete it?

FWIW I second @EmilJeřábek

In light of @EmilJeřábek's comment, I retracted my vote to delete

It seems like I’m way off base here, apologies to anyone upset by this train of thought. Thank you for standing up for me Emil, I appreciate it.

Talking about whether you're happy for AI trainers to "use my input here" to train seems to be either missing the point or conflating two issues. One issue is scraping MO to provide input for training. The other is posting to MO, presumably to validate the output as part of the feedback process of the training. Some people may be happy with the first but not the second. This meta question is primarily about the second, but your answer can be read as responding primarily to the first.

Yes, what @PeterTaylor says is an important point. I think there are legitimate questions about whether organizations should be allowed to use MO (or any other Stack Exchange) content to train their AI systems. But having AI post content (questions or answers) to MO to help with training is infinitely more insidious than that, because it represents using the site in a way different from its intended purpose to help people learn research-level math.
